# How to make hidden child div larger than parent and push next row down when shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://codepen.io/zottewell-1471653998/pen/gmdQze

I'm trying to have each clickable tile show relevant content when it is clicked and take up the full width. In my code above, when the child div is clicked, it only pushes one ".tile" off to the side. In my searching, I found that using ".tile{position: absolute;}" would allow me to make a child bigger than it's parent. I'm really stuck on this and would love some help. Here is my code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tile").on("click", function(){
          $(".show").hide();
          $(this).children("div.show").toggle("fast");
        });
    });
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tile").on("click", function(){
          $(".show").hide();
          $(this).children("div.show").toggle("fast");
        });
    });
```

```css
* {
      width: 80%
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .tile {
      width: 25%;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .show {
      display: none;
      /* position: absolute;
      width: 100; */
    }
```

```html
    <div class="tile">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
      <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
      <div class="show">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
      <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
      <div class="show">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
      <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
      <div class="show">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
      <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
      <div class="show">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
      <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
      <div class="show">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
      <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
      <div class="show">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
      <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
      <div class="show">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
      <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
      <div class="show">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>  
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Help me understand this: Do you want the entire "tile"  (with the 300x300 image) to take up the full width? or just the "Some Text" part? And you want other tiles to be pushed down?

Comment: This would be very easy if each .tile was a table cell that resides in rows..Are you interested in placing a fixed number of tile in each table row and then getting the entire row to shift downwards when a tile above is clicked?

Comment: @GurtejSingh just the some text part needs to take the full width (in other words, the div with the class "show") and then push the row below it down.

Comment: @repzero My issue with that is I couldn't make it responsive, if my understanding of how tables work is correct. I want the amount of tiles in each row to change as the viewport grows. But please correct me if my understanding isn't right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your pen to match your description:
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpLoKr.

I added a flexbox wrapper around all tiles to align your items into rows. I kept your 25% width in place, but you can update that as you wish. When you click on a tile, the show-text class will be toggled and add a margin-bottom to the tile parent, which will push the next row down.

I also updated your click handler, as the logic was inconsistent so it wasn't toggling properly. Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tile").on("click", function(){
      $(".tile:not(.show-text).show").hide();
      $(this).toggleClass("show-text");
      $(this).children("div.show").toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  width: 80%
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tile-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tile {
   width: 25%;
}

.tile.show-text {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.show {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tile-wrapper">
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
  <div class="show">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
  <div class="show">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
  <div class="show">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
  <div class="show">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
  <div class="show">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
  <div class="show">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
  <div class="show">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
  <h3>TITLE</span></h3>
  <div class="show">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate this! I never thought to add a margin to force the push-down. One more quick question if you don't mind, line 3 of the jQuery code you provided is a bit confusing to me. If I'm reading it right, it hides every tile with the class .show but without the class .show-text. Shouldn't those tiles already be hidden?

Comment: Np :) The problem with the previous code is that it wasn't actually toggling the selected item. Here's what was happening every time you clicked on a tile: /n
1. $(".show").hide(); // All tiles were hidden. <br/>
2. $(this).children("div.show").toggle("fast"); // the div that you clicked on would be toggled. <br/>

Therefore, every time you clicked on a tile, you would be immediately hiding it, then calling toggle on it, which would display it again. Toggle never actually hid the currently visible tile if you clicked it twice in a row, since that first line would always be hiding it first.

Comment: So, by adding  $(this).toggleClass("show-text"); the show-text class to the tile you clicked on, and then  $(".tile:not(.show-text).show").hide(); only hiding tiles that do NOT have this class, this line: $(this).children("div.show").toggle("fast"); will now toggle correctly and hide if its visible from before, or show if its still hidden. Let me know if this is clearer :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as growing the number of images as the size of viewport increases is concerned your current implementation would not help you achieve it as you are using floats with 25% width to each. This will always force 4 images on in each row.

As part of a solution to what you are looking for please find the updated pen

[**Live Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeMVxe)

```css
* {
  width: 80% margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  clear: both;
}

.tile {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.show {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute;
      width: 100; */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tile">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <h3>TITLE</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="show">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <h3>TITLE</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="show">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <h3>TITLE</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="show">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <h3>TITLE</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="show">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tile">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <h3>TITLE</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="show">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <h3>TITLE</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="show">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <h3>TITLE</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="show">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <h3>TITLE</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="show">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Is this what you are looking for. Apologies for not commenting as I don't have enough reputation. :)